# How to save Machine Learning models in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am using R to create some basic machine learning models. I use the klar, caret and e1071 packages. Here is the code that generates my model

```
library(e1071)
library(klaR)
library(caret)



x = iris[,-5]

y = iris$Species

model = train(x,y,'nb',trControl = trainControl(method='cv',number=10))
```

i was wondering,is it possible to save this model somewhere and reference it later ? For example, in python we can use the pickle package to do

```
nbClassifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(featureSets)

saveNBClassifier = open("abtNBClassifier.pickle","wb")

pickle.dump(nbClassifier, saveNBClassifier)

saveNBClassifier.close()
```

and later

```
open_file = open("abtNBClassifier.pickle", "rb")

classifier = pickle.load(open_file)

open_file.close()
```

is something similar possible in R ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to save a single object, you can also use:

```
saveRDS(model, file = "model.rds")
```

Afterwards you can use

```
loadedModel <- readRDS(model.rds)
```

ReadRDS() does not load the object as it was named when you saved it, but can be loaded in a new name.

For more information on the difference between save() and saveRDS() see this [link](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/)

Comment: perfect ! exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can just use:

`save(model, file="model.Rda")`

and later:

`load("model.Rda")`

Comment: thanks @tcash21, i am able to save but not load. when i load it as 
loadedModel = load("nbModel.Rda")

and then try to view loadedModel, it shows me

"model"

instead of the actual model

Comment: When you load the model, it will assign it the same name as the object you saved it as, so in your case "model". After loading the object, you should be able to work with it as you normally would (e.g., make predictions with it)

Comment: thanks, but then do i still need to dereference it ? if it will always be loaded as 'model' or whatever name i had saved it as, does it even make sense to do

loadModel = load("model.Rda")

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to do `loadModel = load("model.Rda")`. It does make sense to just do `load("model.Rda")`, as in the answer. If you then want to do `loadModel = model` to rename it that's up to you.